# polling selection in finder from a processing app

Tags: applescript, processing, daemon, finder

i'm making a simple processing app for a presentation which currently does one thing : it listens to a microphone and emulates a right arrow key down event when it hears sound. I'm using it to synchronize [a synth](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IApamM65si4) with the OSX finder, so when i play music it iterates through the files of a folder, as if i was pressing repeatedly on the right arrow on my keyboard.

> my problem is that the app gets stuck when it hits the last file in a folder. The app needs to be aware of that so it can emulate a left arrow keydown event & a down arrow keydown event to go up a directory and carry on iterating.

I've tried calling applescript from processing to do that, which kind of works, but it's too slow and takes the focus away from the finder, then gives it back, which just looks glitchy (which is important as i'm making this app for a presentation).

I'm guessing i could maybe use a daemon polling which element is currently being selected in the finder, and sending that path to the processing app, and taking action if the path doesn't change after a keypress ; but then i'm not sure how to do that. Can python or bash poll that kind of info from the finder?

thank you!

```
import processing.sound.*;
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
Amplitude amp;
AudioIn in;
Robot robot;

void setup() {
  size(1, 1);  
    try { 
    robot = new Robot();
  } catch (AWTException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    exit();
  }

  Sound s = new Sound(this);
  s.inputDevice(3);
  // select audio device ; if not available will fall back to default input
  amp = new Amplitude(this);
  in = new AudioIn(this, 0);
  in.start();
  amp.input(in);
  in.play();
  // playback of audio input : will larsen if you use computer's mic
}      

void draw() {
  // println(amp.analyze());
  if(amp.analyze()>0.3){
    println("go");
    // if sound is louder than 0.3 press right key
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT);

    delay(200); 
    // prob not the right delay
}
}
```

Comment: It's going to be pretty hard to help without seeing any code. Can you post a [mcve]? (Maybe use the `mousePressed()` function instead of an external synth, so we can run the code.)

Comment: hi! thank you for your feedback. I edited the post with workable code : open a finder window & tap in your hands to see the selection go downwards.